# Gromov compactness theorem for genus $g >0$ Riemann surfaces

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, gromov-witten-theory, symplectic-topology

In McDuff & Salamon's book "J-holomorphic Curves and Symplectic Topology", only the Gromov compactness for spheres has been proved, and I wonder whether or not this compactness result is still true for genus $g>0$ Riemann surfaces.

If there does exist such a generalization of Gromov compactness, then does there exist any reference that contains detailed proof of it? It seems that the techniques used in this book are hard to apply for the case of arbitrary genus.

I prefer a proof using the notion of stable maps as in this book.

Comment: The first step is to do a very quick google search and/or look for references in the McDuff-Salamon book: *"Gromov's compactness theorem for pseudo holomorphic curves"* by Rugang Ye (reference 310 of that book). Also see *"Pseudo-holomorphic maps and bubble trees"* by Parker-Wolfson.

Comment: Also see Christoph Hummel's book "Gromov's compactness theorem for pseudo-holomorphic curves" for a detailed geometric proof.

Answer (score 1):

MR1451624 
Hummel, Christoph,
Gromov's compactness theorem for pseudo-holomorphic curves. 
Progress in Mathematics, 151. Birkhäuser Verlag, Basel, 1997.